# How do I get the raw time-ticks with SNMPSharpNet?

Tags: c#, snmp

I am writing an application to monitor SNMP devices and save the data into SQL. But I am running into problems with timeticks.

Most values are easily recordable as floats. The raw timeticks number would also be very easy to store. However, SNMPSharpNet, when I run `(SnmpV1Packet)target.Request(pdu, param);` returns a string with the value decoded: `0d 4h 56m 0s 0ms`

I suppose I could parse this value, but it seems a waste of cycles to convert the number twice. How do I get the raw number of milliseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried casting the `AsnType` to `SnmpSharpNet.TimeTicks`:

```
UdpTarget target = new UdpTarget(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1"));
Pdu pdu = new Pdu(PduType.Get);
pdu.VbList.Add("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0");
AgentParameters param = new AgentParameters(SnmpVersion.Ver1, new OctetString("public"));
SnmpV1Packet packet = (SnmpV1Packet)target.Request(pdu, param);
AsnType uptimeAsn = packet.Pdu.VbList["1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"].Value;

long uptime = ((TimeTicks)uptimeAsn).Milliseconds;

Console.WriteLine(uptime);
Console.WriteLine(new TimeSpan(0,0,(int)(uptime/1000)));
```

Just make sure to surround this with try/catch, in case the cast fails.

Comment: I added a better example. Looking at it now I think you are using `packet.Pdu.VbList["1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"]` instead of `packet.Pdu.VbList["1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"].Value`. You can also use the SimpleSnmp class, it's simpler than using the UdpTarget.